# How to set foreground on a part of text in the setter of a trigger?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have the need to write part of the text inside a button with a different foreground. Until now, following [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38305358/how-to-set-foreground-on-part-of-multi-binding-when-concatenating-two-properties), i was using the following piece of code:

```
<Button>
  <TextBlock Margin="20"
           FontSize="24"
           FontStyle="Normal"
           FontWeight="Medium"
           Foreground="#FF1384F5">
       <Run>text1</Run>
       <Run Foreground="#FF1372D3" Text="{Binding MyBinding}"/>
       <Run >text2</Run>
   </TextBlock>
</Button>
```

now i have the need to change the whole text based on a trigger, so i builded a DataTriger like the following:

```
<TextBlock.Style>
     <Style TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
         <Style.Triggers>
             <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding MyBoolean}" Value="True">
                 <Setter Property="Text">
                      <Setter.Value>
                           <Run>text1</Run>
                           <Run Foreground="#FF1372D3" Text="{Binding MyBinding}"/>
                           <Run >text2</Run>
                      </Setter.Value>
                  </Setter>
              </DataTrigger>
             <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding MyBoolean}" Value="False">
                 <Setter Property="Text" Value="text3" />
              </DataTrigger>
          </Style.Triggers>
      </Style>
</TextBlock.Style>
```

of course this doesn't work because the property value is setted more than once. Looking for a solution i found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28192277/multiple-run-elements-in-wpf-style-setter) . It basically says to use multi binding

```
<Setter.Value>
    <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0}{1}{2}"><!-- Format as you wish -->
        <Binding Path="SelectedItem.iso"/>
        <Binding Source="{x:Static System:Environment.NewLine}"/>
        <Binding Path="SelectedItem.value"/>
    </MultiBinding>
</Setter.Value>
```

But i'm not sure if it fit my situation, and how to use it eventually.

Comment: Remove the text from `TextBlock` and place it in your style. Then the trigger will work.

Comment: @XAMlMAX sorry but what do you mean by that? When is set the DataTrigger i remove the Content from my textblock

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Run`s will be set to the `TextBlock.Inlines` property, which has only getter, no setter. So you can't set `Run`s in the Style.

You can use two `TextBlock` elements and bind `MyBoolean` to the `Visibility` property of them:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
        <local:BoolToVisConverter x:Key="btoviscnv"/>
    </Grid.Resources>
    <TextBlock Text="text3" Visibility="{Binding MyBoolean, Converter={StaticResource btoviscnv}, ConverterParameter='not'}"/>
    <TextBlock Visibility="{Binding MyBoolean, Converter={StaticResource btoviscnv}}">
        <Run>text1</Run>
        <Run Foreground="#FF1372D3" Text="{Binding MyBinding}"/>
        <Run>text2</Run>
    </TextBlock>
</Grid>

public class BoolToVisConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var bvalue = (bool)value;
        if ((parameter as string)?.Equals("not") ?? false)
        {
            bvalue = !bvalue;
        }
        return bvalue ? System.Windows.Visibility.Visible : System.Windows.Visibility.Collapsed;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException("It's one way converter");
    }
}
```

Comment: Although this is a good solution, i wrote that this Texblock is actually inside the content of a button. I specify that at the beginning, but it's not written in the code. My bad, i'm going to edit

Comment: Make a `Grid` to be a content of the `Button`.

Comment: i get so used to the triggers that i can't think to such simply solution. Thanks